# C# process.Start filename and passing arguments

Tags: c#, ms-access, cmd

I need to open the file test.mdb.
The path must be fullpath built from whatever directory it is located in relative to the C# program exe

I need to pass the Arguments line which in batch would be passed like this /cmd "MyArgument"
For the /cmd switch to work the path must include the full path to the installed MSACCESS.EXE

I just can't work out how to pass the full path to MSACCESS>EXE followed by the fullpath to test.mdb followed by the Arguments.

To try to help I'm posting the following batch string which works but I need C#

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office10\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Test Examples Folder\test.mdb" /cmd "MyArgument"

To make clear two important points:

The test.mdb fullpath must be automatically determined by the launching C# exe it will be the C# exes path but with test.mdb.

And the MSACCESS>EXE path must be the full path to the installed version of MSACCESS.EXE if the C# exe program can automatically check which version i.e. Office 10, Office 12 etc and use that this would be excellent.

This is my code so far:

```
var filePath = @"test.mdb";

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/cmd " + "\"MyArgument\"";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.Start();
```

Comment: The path to the db file would be one of your arguments.

Comment: Getting the test.mdb full path is simple enough:
change

`var filePath = @"test.mdb";`

to

`string filePath = new System.IO.FileInfo("test.mdb").FullName;`

Comment: juharr  & Mvarta  I tried that but it doesn't work can you post  the working code example that address all the points in my post include any using references etc so that the code compiles Im new to C# and can't get it to work so a working example of code that address all my points would be good for me thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about detecting the office version, just this should work for you:

```
        string filepath = '"' + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\test.mdb" + '"';
        string acc_cmd_arg = "HELLO";

        using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process() )  {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "msaccess.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = filepath + " /cmd " + acc_cmd_arg;
            process.Start(); 
        }
```